# Angular how can I use embed script in Component

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, twitch

I'm trying to set up in Angular a way of only showing Twitch player if the stream is online, so in the [Documentation](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/embed/video-and-clips/) there is this inline HTML:

```
<script src= "https://player.twitch.tv/js/embed/v1.js"></script>
<div id="<player div ID>"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var options = {
    width: <width>,
    height: <height>,
    channel: "<channel ID>",
    video: "<video ID>",
    collection: "<collection ID>",
  };
  var player = new Twitch.Player("<player div ID>", options);
  player.setVolume(0.5);
</script>
```

Of course though in Angular Components we can't use < script > tags and I don't think it's currently possible to use require or import to use this in my components TypeScript.

So how would I go about adding this functionality? I understand what to do after I can actually reference that script tag.

Comment: why don't you include the script in "scripts" in angular.json?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a script tag dynamically, but I think it's easier to just download the script and put it in assets folder and then add the script to script list in `angular.json`

or you can add the script to `index.html` head section

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <script src= "https://player.twitch.tv/js/embed/v1.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
```

add this to component `ngOninit` method

```js
      ngOnInit() {
        var options = {
            width: <width>,
            height: <height>,
            channel: "<channel ID>",
            video: "<video ID>",
            collection: "<collection ID>",
          };
          var player = new Twitch.Player("<player div ID>", options);
          player.setVolume(0.5);
       }
```

*Component template*

```html
    <div id="<player div ID>"></div>
```

You may find another solution like angular package for twitch can be more cleaner way

**Updated**

typescript will give an error like `[ts] Cannot find name 'Twitch'. [2304]` some library has type definition files but in our case if you use Twitch object in this file only you can add this statement to tell typescript about the `Twitch` object

```
declare const Twitch: any;
```

if you want to use Twitch on multiple components

src/global.d.ts

```
 declare const Twitch: any;
```

**final recommendation**

install `npm i twitch-js` and import Twitch object like this

`import Twitch from 'twitch-js'`

this will be bundled by webpack, so you don't need to add any script tag in the html.

[twitch-devs](https://github.com/twitch-devs/twitch-js)

Comment: The second doesn't work it still says 'Cannot find name 'Twitch''

Comment: The first way also doesn't seem to do anything either it still says the same as the above comment :/

Comment: @DanielTurcich sorry forgot to mention `declare const Twitch: any`

Comment: I'm getting `ERROR TypeError: Twitch.Player is not a constructor` when i include it in the head, or download/include it

Answer (score 1):

Struggled with this for a while. My script was asynchronous, and eventually I discovered [postscribe package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postscribe). Works like magic.

```
npm install --save postscribe
```

In the code:

```js
import postscribe from 'postscribe'

//The script you want to load
const script = '<script src="https://darksky.net/map-embed/@radar,41.88,-87.62,10.js?embed=true&timeControl=false&fieldControl=false&defaultField=radar"></script>';

postscribe('#yourDivName', script);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I made it work:

1. Copy everything from [Twitch JS URL](https://player.twitch.tv/js/embed/v1.js).
2. **Create** file `twitch.js` in your assets folder and **paste** everything. ( `src/assets/scripts/twitch.js` ).
3. In your component add `import Twitch from 'src/assets/scripts/twitch.js'`.
4. Also in your component add the twitch init code

Your component should look like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import Twitch from 'src/assets/scripts/twitch.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  embedTwitch! : any;
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.embedTwitch = new Twitch.Embed("twitch-embed", {
      width: 854,
      height: 480,
      channel: "monstercat"
    });
  }

}
```

5. Your component html must have twitch placeholder `<div id="twitch-embed"></div>`
6. Open your app and enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Manually download the `v1.js` script from https://embed.twitch.tv/embed/v1.js
2. Create new folder `src/twitch/` and add the `v1.js` script to it
3. Add `"src/twitch/v1.js"` to the `scripts` array in `angular.json`
4. Create a new file `twitch.d.ts` in `src/twitch/`
5. Add `declare const Twitch: any;` to `twitch.d.ts`

The Twitch library can now be used anywhere **without importing any module** like so:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  new Twitch.Embed('containerId', {
    channel: 'asmongold',
    height: 500,
    width: 400,
 });
}
```