# How can I use a Twitch <script> tag in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, twitch

I'm trying to achieve the same functionality as I did in Angular [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53577637/angular-how-can-i-use-embed-script-in-component) but inside **Vue.JS** (2.6+).

I'm trying to use the [Twitch API for embedding a Stream](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/embed/video-and-clips/) and it only shows usage via this inline HTML:

```
<script src= "https://player.twitch.tv/js/embed/v1.js"></script>
<div id="<player div ID>"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var options = {
    width: <width>,
    height: <height>,
    channel: "<channel ID>",
    video: "<video ID>",
    collection: "<collection ID>",
  };
  var player = new Twitch.Player("<player div ID>", options);
  player.setVolume(0.5);
</script>
```

And the same as in Angular we can't use Script tags in Vue Components of course.

**So I was wondering what would be the best way in Vue to utilize this Twitch Embed  inside of my Vue application?** *(I'm fine with it living inside the JS or in the HTML of the component)*

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the twitch library like any other library. If you do not find it within `npm`, you can just download it and import it locally. It seems, that it is not an ES6 module, so it will assign the library to the global window object, where you can use it from then on.

*Here is an example:*

main.js

```
import './libraries/twitch.v1.js';

// boilerplate your vue app
```

component:

```
<template>
  <div ref="twitchVideo" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'twitch-video',
  data () {
    return { player: null }
  },
  mounted () {
    const options = {
      width: 854,
      height: 480,
      channel: 'dallas',
    };
    // you might need to pass an ID string as a first argument..
    this.player = new Twitch.Player(this.$refs.twitchVideo, options);
    this.player.setVolume(0.5);
  }
};
</script>
```

---

Another option would be to just add the `<script>` tag to your index.html file. I would however advise you against that, because you don't know when the script is loaded from within a component and it goes against the whole concept of bundling your libraries.

Comment: I attempted this today, copying the contents of the JS file and bringing it it into the component. It didn't end up working properly though, so I had to resort to sticking it into the index.html. Is there anything I should look into?

Comment: Did you copy the JS file to your local machine and did you import it like proposed (with `import`)? What happened after the import? Was the Twitch object defined (`console.log(Twitch)`)?

Comment: Yes to both. When the iframe loaded, it did so with my localhost as the source - creating a loop of sources - which was weird. The proper path didn't get loaded or something. It worked fine when including in the head of the html document though. :/